# How can I combine a DStream pair of key and value using the same key?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, datastax-enterprise

I want to change the first DStream to become the second using spark. But I don't know how to do this? I already tried groupByKey(), which didn't work and aggregateByKey(), which only uses RDD not DStream.

This is the current result:

```
DStream [(1,value1),(2,value2),(3,value3),(1,value4),(1,value5),(2,value6)]
```

This is the result I want:

```
DStream(1,(value1,value4,value5)) ,(2,(value2,value5)) ,(3,(value3))
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: What do you mean by `groupByKey` _didn't work_?

Comment: Using the same key with groupByKey does not give me the same key and value pair when I combine them. Meaning it does not give me this result: DStream(1,(value1,value4,value5)) ,(2,(value2,value5)) ,(3,(value3)). I don't know how to do this maybe I am using groupByKey wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupByKey` does exactly this. It converts `DStream[K, V]` into `DStream[(K, Seq[V])]`. I suspect that your expectations about the output may be wrong. Since `DStream` is just an infinite sequence of `RDDs` group is applied to each `RDD` individually. So if the first batch contains:

```
(1,value1),(2,value2),(3,value3),(1,value4)
```

and the second

```
(1,value5),(2,value6)
```

you'll get

```
(1, [value1, value4]), (2, [value2]), (3, value3)
```

and

```
(1,[value5]),(2,[value6])
```

respectively.

While `DStreams` support stateful operations (`updateStateByKey`) it is rather unlikely you want to use this with growing collections.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Using groupByKey does not allow me to combine the same key pair since it is a stream and uses several RDD's/growing collection. What solution do you propose in my case achieving the result described above? Thanks

Comment: It is not clear for me what you are trying to achieve. I mean that a growing values in stream will simply blow the memory sooner or later. If you want to keep everything just persist (and maybe read when needed). If you to look at the wider interval try window operations.

Comment: I am not sure what data amount spark streaming can handle and when to substitute stream with database analysis. Here is my more detailed question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691172/whats-the-limit-to-spark-streaming-in-terms-of-data-amount . Thanks for the reply and help!

Comment: It don't think there is a hard limit other than memory limitations for a single data structure. Probably long before that you'll some other performance issues like intensive spilling to disk or GC. On a side note - if this answers that part part of the question please don't forget to upvote / accept.